# Creating a table and Inserting values in db browser (sqlite)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, browser, sql-insert

I am new at scripting and am trying to create a table and insert values into the table below using DB Browser (SQLite).

```
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Doctor" (
    "Doctorid"  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    "DoctorName"    TEXT NOT NULL,
    "DoctorSpecialty"   TEXT NOT NULL,
    "ConsultationFee"   NUMERIC NOT NULL
    );
    INSERT INTO Doctor 
    (Doctorid,DoctorName,DoctorSpecialty,ConsultationFee) VALUES 
    (1,'Wells','Respiritory Therapy',300),
    INSERT INTO Doctor 
    (Doctorid,DoctorName,DoctorSpecialty,ConsultationFee) VALUES 
    (2,'Rose','Cardiology',375),
    INSERT INTO Doctor 
    (Doctorid,DoctorName,DoctorSpecialty,ConsultationFee) VALUES 
    (3,'Johnson','Neurology',250),
    INSERT INTO Doctor 
    (Doctorid,DoctorName,DoctorSpecialty,ConsultationFee) VALUES 
    (4,'Leath','Pharmacy',400),
    INSERT INTO Doctor 
    (Doctorid,DoctorName,DoctorSpecialty,ConsultationFee) VALUES 
    (5,'Anderson','Anesthesiology',500),
    INSERT INTO Doctor 
    (Doctorid,DoctorName,DoctorSpecialty,ConsultationFee) VALUES 
    (6,'Copeland','Radiology',550),
    INSERT INTO Doctor 
    (Doctorid,DoctorName,DoctorSpecialty,ConsultationFee) VALUES 
    (7,'Macklin','Orthopedic Surgeon',575),
    INSERT INTO Doctor 
    (Doctorid,DoctorName,DoctorSpecialty,ConsultationFee) VALUES 
    (8,'Witherspoon','Immunizations',100),
    INSERT INTO Doctor 
    (Doctorid,DoctorName,DoctorSpecialty,ConsultationFee) VALUES 
    (9,'Pope','Billing',50),
    INSERT INTO Doctor 
    (Doctorid,DoctorName,DoctorSpecialty,ConsultationFee) VALUES  
    (10,'Cockfield','Pediatrics',100);
    COMMIT;
```

Once I run the script, I receive an error:

```
    Result: near "INSERT": syntax error
    At line 7:
    INSERT INTO Doctor 
    (Doctorid,DoctorName,DoctorSpecialty,ConsultationFee) VALUES 
    (1,'Wells','Respiritory Therapy',300),
    INSERT
```

Line 7 is: );

Im not sure what im doing wrong, can someone please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove Doctorid at insert time because it is AUTOINCREMENT.

```
 INSERT INTO Doctor 
        (DoctorName,DoctorSpecialty,ConsultationFee) VALUES 
        ('Wells','Respiritory Therapy',300);
```

and put the semicolon (;) end of the query

Answer (score 0):

Inserting multiple values should be like this. You don't need to repeat `INSERT` statement.

```
INSERT INTO Doctor 
    (Doctorid,DoctorName,DoctorSpecialty,ConsultationFee) VALUES 
    (1,'Wells','Respiritory Therapy',300),
    (2,'Rose','Cardiology',375),    
    (3,'Johnson','Neurology',250),  
    (4,'Leath','Pharmacy',400);
```

**or** change the `comma` to `semi colon` in each `INSERT` statement.

```
INSERT INTO Doctor 
    (Doctorid,DoctorName,DoctorSpecialty,ConsultationFee) VALUES 
    (1,'Wells','Respiritory Therapy',300);
INSERT INTO Doctor 
    (Doctorid,DoctorName,DoctorSpecialty,ConsultationFee) VALUES 
    (2,'Rose','Cardiology',375);
```